# Reusable Modal Component React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, reactstrap

I have a component which has a button within it, like so -

```
<Button variant="primary" disabled={checkAccepted} onClick={openModal}>Send</Button>
```

I would like this button to, when it is active, to open up a modal when clicked. I am unsure how to do this and have been messing around with props but can't seem to figure it out. I also want the modal to be reusable so that any content can be passed in the modal body.I am thinking how do I open up the modal from within my openModal function?
I tried returning it like so -

```
const openModal = () => {

return (
            <Modal>
                <ModalBody>*Pass in swappable content here*</ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        )
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I am sure I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return components from an event handler. The way to handle events in react is almost always to alter the state of your application which triggers a re-render. In your case you need to keep track of the `open` state of your modal.

This can be done either in a controlled way (you keep track of the open state yourself and pass it to your `<Modal>` component as a prop) or in an uncontrolled way (the `<Modal>` component manages the `open` state itself). The second approach requires that you provide e.g. an element to render to your `Modal` component that acts as a trigger:

```
const MyModal = ({ children, trigger }) => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);

  return (
    <div>
      {React.cloneElement(trigger, { onClick: toggle })}
      <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle}>
        <ModalBody>{children}</ModalBody>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
<MyModal trigger={<Button variant="primary">Send</Button>}>
    <p>This is the content.</p>
</MyModal>
```

[image: Edit quizzical-sunset-wzjfu]

Or you can implement it in a controlled way. This is more flexible as it allows you to render the triggering element anywhere:

```
const MyModal = ({ children, isOpen, toggle }) => (
  <div>
    <Modal isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle}>
      <ModalBody>{children}</ModalBody>
    </Modal>
  </div>
);
```

Usage Example:

```
function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={toggle}>
        Send
      </Button>
      <MyModal isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle}>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
      </MyModal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit keen-cray-7pf5k]

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the function which triggers the modal to your `<Button />` component as prop. Then, in your  component, you want to add the onClick event. You can't set an onClick event to the `<Button />`. It will think of onClick as a prop being passed to `<Button />`. Within `<Button />` you can set the onClick event to an actual `<button>` element, and use the function which was passed in as a prop on that event.

You can use state to keep track of when the modal button is clicked. Your function can look like: (I am using class based components here, but you can do the same thing with functional components)

```
buttonClickedHandler = () => {
    this.setState({isModalButtonClicked: !this.state.isModalButtonClicked});
}
```

Then, you can set the Modal component,

```
<Modal isShow={this.state.isModalButtonClicked} modalButton={this.buttonClickedHandler}>
   <div> ...set contents of modal</div>
</Modal>

<button onClick={this.buttonClickedHandler}>Show Modal</button>
```

So, within the Modal component, you can have something like this:

```
<React.Fragment>
    <Backdrop showModal={this.props.isShow} clicked={this.props.modalButton}/>
    {this.props.children}
</React.Fragment>
```

Backdrop is basically the greyed out background. You can also set an onClick event to listen to when the backdrop is clicked.